# Не находит класс Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, kernel

Выбрасывает ошибку **Class App\Http\App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAAdmin does not exist** . С чем может быть связано?

Файл **RedirectIfNotAAdmin.php** находящийся в папке **Middleware**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RedirectIfNotAAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $request ->user()->isATeamAdmin()){
            return redirect('/');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Файл **Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'admin' => App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAAdmin::class
    ];
```

В файл **User.php** добавил такой код

```
public function isATeamAdmin(){
        return true;
    }
```

Ну и собственно роут в **Web.php**

```
Route::get('/news',['middleware' => 'admin',
    'uses'=>'PageController@news'
]);
```

Comment: Посмотрите на namespace класса и полный путь класса в ошибке. Они не совпадают. Возможно, нужно указать так `'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAAdmin::class`

Comment: @ArchDemon круто,действительно в этом проблема. Но теперь вот такую ошибку выкидывает **Call to a member function isATeamAdmin() on null**

Comment: @RedLionHeart потому что юзер = null

Comment: @AntonKucenko но я ведь просто пытаюсь попробовать. говорит что isATeamAdmin равен нулю, а в ней я возвращаю просто true. Как исправить подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: @RedLionHeart не метод равняется null, а юзер. Переведите ошибку.

Comment: @AntonKucenko, надеюсь ошибка понятна. @RedLionHeart очень грамотно помог решить проблему. Для красоты кода можешь модифицировать условие так `if(!optional($request->user())->isATeamAdmin())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть предположение, что если пользователь будет не авторизован, возникнет подобная ошибка. Попробуй поставить дополнительное условие в `if` на авторизацию пользователя, а уже потом на его свойства и методы:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RedirectIfNotAAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->user() || !$request->user()->isATeamAdmin()){
            return redirect('/');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: все верно, я уже сделал так